# syntax error, unexpected ')', expecting '='

Tags: ruby, markdown, jekyll, redcarpet

I'm writing an extension for Redcarpet for a Jekyll-powered website. I want to use `{x|y}` as a tag in markdown that evaluates to the HTML `<ruby>` tag (and its associates). I wrote this class as per [Jekyll's guide](http://jekyllrb.com/docs/configuration/#custom-markdown-processors), [Redcarpet's guide](http://dev.af83.com/2012/02/27/howto-extend-the-redcarpet2-markdown-lib.html), and [this guide](http://dev.af83.com/2012/02/27/howto-extend-the-redcarpet2-markdown-lib.html) on how to do so:

```rb
class Jekyll::Converters::Markdown::HotelDown < Redcarpet::Render::HTML
    def preprocess(doc)
        s = "<ruby><rb>\\1</rb><rp>(</rp><rt>\\2</rt><rp>)</rp></ruby>"
        doc.gs­ub!(/\[([\­s\S]+)\|([­\s\S]+)\]/­, s)
        doc
    end
end
```

But, I seem to be getting a couple errors when I run `bundle exec jekyll serve`:

```
Configuration file: C:/Users/Alex/OneDrive/codes/hotelc.me/hotelc.me/_config.yml
plugin_manager.rb:58:in `require': HotelDown.rb:4: syntax error, unexpected tIDENTIFIER, expecting ')' (SyntaxError)
            doc.gs-ub!(/\[([\-s\S]+)\|([-\s\S]+)\]/-, s)
                                                        ^
HotelDown.rb:4: syntax error, unexpected ')', expecting '='
            doc.gs-ub!(/\[([\-s\S]+)\|([-\s\S]+)\]/-, s)
                                                            ^
```

It seems there's something wrong with my syntax (an extra space, missing parentheses, or something like that). Is there something I've missed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code has some special characters which is causing this error:

```
syntax error, unexpected ')', expecting '='
            doc.gs-ub!(/\[([\-s\S]+)\|([-\s\S]+)\]/-, s)
```

Replace your current code with this piece of code:

```
class Jekyll::Converters::Markdown::HotelDown < Redcarpet::Render::HTML
  #Overriding the preprocess() function
  def preprocess(doc)
    s = "<ruby><rb>\\1</rb><rp>(</rp><rt>\\2</rt><rp>)</rp></ruby>"
    doc.gsub!(/\[([\s\S]+)\|([\s\S]+)\]/, s)
    doc
  end
end

markdown = Redcarpet::Markdown.new(HotelDown)
```

and it should work!

Comment: Ah! Of course: when I first wrote the code, I accidentally typed some of the characters using the Japanese keyboard.

Comment: Also, I was wondering what those dashes in the stacktrace were... and now I know. Thanks!